# What are these holes on the intake of Progress D-18T which are mounted on AN-225?

Tags: jet-engine, turbofan, inlet

I was seeing a Progress D-18T of AN-225 and saw these holes on the intake of them. What are they for?

[image: Progress D-18T intake]

Comment: My guess is exhaust holes for cowl anti-ice bleed.

Comment: @JohnK I was going to say the same thing. You beat me to it. :)